# React Hooks - Setting a className in a map() function only to one item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm mapping through a list of items, and when one is clicked, I want to change the color of it to pink. I'm using hooks to set the state, but the problem is, when one item is clicked, they all turn pink (so are all assigned the className.

```
const ButtonCustom = () => {

    const [menuState, setMenuState] = React.useState(false);

    let className = "RichEditor-styleButton"
    {
        menuActive === true?
        className += " RichEditor-styleButton-active":(null)
    }
    return (
        <span
          className={className}
          onClick={() => setMenuState(!menuActive)}
        >
            {value}
        </span>
      );
  }


const Home = () => {
    return(
      <div>
          {items.map((button) => {
              return ButtonCustom();
          })}
    </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: where do you store menuActive and how it is being changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a weird syntax. I would have rewritten it like this:

```
const ButtonCustom = () => {

    const [menuActive, setMenuActive] = React.useState(false);

    let className = "RichEditor-styleButton"
    if (menuActive === true) {
        className += " RichEditor-styleButton-active";
    }
    return (
        <span
          className={className}
          onClick={() => setMenuActive(active=>!active)}
        >
            {value}
        </span>
      );
  }


const Home = () => {
    return(
      <div>
          {items.map((button, index) => {
              return <ButtonCustom key={index}/>;
          })}
    </div>
    )
}
```

Mostly concerned about ambiguous menuActive/menuState and the {} block after string definition. Also note the "key" attribute on the **Home** component